# How to check if current user belongs to SharePoint group

Tags: 2007, javascript, groups, user

I have a custom list with a script (JavaScript) allowing me to add some features/customisations to my list.

More precisely, I have a function in my script which creates an hyperlink according to a reference (in my columns' fields). I would like to call this function only if the logged user belong to a specific SharePoint Group.

I'm using SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) and JavaScript (without jQuery neither Designer).

**Edit:** It's a little more tricky because I have to check if the user belongs to a specific SharePoint Group, but within several sites. The SharePoint Group is a little different throw each sites, for example :

> siteA Managers (in site A)
>
> siteB Managers (in site B)

So, I would like to only check if the current user belongs to "Managers", it will match for all the sites.
Is it possible de make a comparison like *Managers or something like that, I'm not very handy with JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Groups for an User using the Web Service [GetGroupCollectionFromUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772552.aspx).

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) can help you; but it's using jQuery. Same thing with [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/).

You'll have to send a SOAP envelope (XML) to the Web Service. The body of your AJAX request will look like that:

```
    var body = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>"
    + "<soap:Body><GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/'>"
    + "<userLoginName>"+username+"</userLoginName>"
    + "</GetGroupCollectionFromUser></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```